# Laravel － How to include External JS file (contains Ajax )

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I use ajax to post the value I selected. It works fine with the following code.
And I want to separate the **jvascript** file from **index.blade.php**.

## **web.php**

```
Route::get('Homepage', function (){
    return view('frontend.index');
});

Route::post('Homepage/filter', 'Frontend\ImgListController@filter')
    ->name('Homepage.filter');
```

## **controller**

```
function filter(Request $request)
    {    
        $get_Model = $request->get('Model');
        Log::debug($get_Model);    
    }
```

If I have my "view" code like the below, the selected value can be correctly post to the url:"{{ route('Homepage.filter') }}".

## **index.blade.php**

```
<html>
<head></head>    
<body>
   <div class="form-group">
      <select name="Model" id="Model">
         <option value="">Select Model</option>
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
      </select>

      <button class="btn" onclick="Fun();">submit</button>

   </div>

   {{ csrf_field() }}

   <script src="{{ asset('jquery/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>

</body>
</html>

<script>
   function Fun() {
     if ($('#Model').val() != '') {
       var model_value = $('#Model').val();

       $.ajax({
         url: "{{ route('Homepage.filter') }}",
         type: "POST",
         data: {
             Model: model_value,
             _token: '{{csrf_token()}}'
         },
         success: function (result) {
         //
         }
       })    
     }    
  }
</script>
```

However, when I try to add this `<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('js/jquery.js') }}"></script>` into **index.blade.php**, and independently out of a jvascript file (public\js\JS.js).
I would get error message bellow.

> POST http://localhost:8888/%7B%7B%20route('Homepage.filter')%20%7D%7D
>   404 (Not Found)

## index.blade.php (Modified, and somewhere wrong)

```
<html>
<head></head>    
<body>
   <div class="form-group">
      <select name="Model" id="Model">
         <option value="">Select Model</option>
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
      </select>

      <button class="btn" onclick="Fun();">submit</button>

   </div>

   {{ csrf_field() }}

   <script src="{{ asset('jquery/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('js/JS.js') }}"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

## javascript

```
function Fun() {
    if ($('#Model').val() != '') {
        var model_value = $('#Model').val();

        $.ajax({
            url: "{{ route('Homepage.filter') }}",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                Model: model_value,
                _token: '{{csrf_token()}}'
            },
            success: function (result) {
                //
            }
        })
    }
}
```

The route *{{ route('Homepage.filter') }}* is wrong? Or anything else? What can I do to correct it ? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You cant write laravel blade syntax inside `.js` file.**

so you cant give direct route name for ajax url

you can call this direct putting the URL of route.

**and for pass token data,**

just place the token in your meta tag inside head of html

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

and then you can attach the token data in your js

```
function Fun() {
    if ($('#Model').val() != '') {
        var model_value = $('#Model').val();
        var token = $('meta[name="csrf_token"]').attr('content'),
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Homepage/filter",
            type: "POST",

            data: {
                Model: model_value,
                _token: token 
            },
            success: function (result) {
                //
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems that missing "header" in `$.ajax()`?!  After I added `headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                },` it works. Thanks a lot！

Answer (score 3):

You can do by this way :

Add below line into your main layout file.

```
@stack('scripts')
```

than put below script at end of your index file.

```
@push('scripts')
     <script src="{{ asset('assets/js/JS.js')}}"></script>
@endpush
```